# Is there a giant 'asset page' of all Bootstrap elements that I can re-style?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html

See all the example elements, like `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `inputs`, etc?

I'm looking for a simple webpage that has every single Bootstrap `inputs/forms/elements/etc` on it, and nothing else.

Then I can get our designer to modify the base CSS file with his own styles, and can refresh the asset page to see all of his changes and how the entire style guide is shaping up.

It'd be very helpful for our team to refer to, and for our client, so he can see our entire 'look and feel' on one consolidated page.

Does such a page exist anywhere??

Comment: People don't seem to be understanding the question here. What the op is asking for would be incredibly useful, a single page you can have on your site (maybe an admin page) that shows every bootstrap element. We're basically talking about the pages at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ but with your styling applied. Think an automatic style guide.

Answer (score 43):

At time of writing, this is a good one for BS3
http://bootply.com/render/71500

Update Decembre 2013:
Bootswatch has a page that is updated regularly
http://bootswatch.com/default/

Update March 2018:
Bootswatch has been updated for BS4.

Comment: This one used version 3-rc1, it looks bad rendered with version 3.0.0,. Here's a similar document that renders nicely with 3.0.0: https://github.com/divshot/bootstrap-theme-white-plum/blob/master/examples/kitchen-sink.html

Comment: Here's a demo of the above source: http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap-theme-white-plum/examples/kitchen-sink.html

Comment: This one is based on 3.0.0 - http://bootply.com/65566

Comment: **Updated** for the latest **Bootstrap 4**: https://www.codeply.com/go/fZsVG07ACV

Comment: I am working on one here [bootstrapononepage](https://bootstrapononepage.github.io)

Comment: @Peter: your link is broken :(

Answer (score 13):

**Bootstrap TLDR** contains all components in one page:
https://anvoz.github.io/bootstrap-tldr/

It's on Github as well:
https://github.com/anvoz/bootstrap-tldr

Answer (score 7):

I have been looking for a similar thing. The best I've found is this website, which also allows you to edit the css on it.

http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/index.html#!/editor

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same need, bootstrap has this ready for you:

1) go to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html and download Bootstrap Source

2) unzip and navigate to "less\tests"

3) there you'll find, as bootstrap puts it "One stop shop for quick debugging and edge-case tests of CSS"

Comment: The current Bootstrap tarball does not or no longer contain a less/tests folder

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one, so I created my own. I basically combined all the example pages of the documentation and stripped out all the descriptions and codes. I also removed some duplicates.

Based on Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6

https://github.com/gavsiu/bootstrap-demo

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is customise the bootstrap docs site to use your stylesheet. It's included in the bootstrap repo at  (on github at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/index.html).

To use a different stylesheet you'll need to update  https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/templates/layout.mustache to point to your stylesheet:

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- add your stylesheet here to override -->
```

and then build using:

```
$ node docs/build production
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look here, a full list of CSS and components, with some explanation and code snipets:

http://codepen.io/letanure/full/WxwaZP/

*Some days ago I need the same thing, dont find anything as I need, so I created this one.*

*randon piece of code, because stackoverflow require if post a link to codepen*

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap all elements</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
```