# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - test html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing my own theme based on Twitter Bootstrap 3.x and want to be sure that I implement all styles for all elements properly. So I have decided that it would be great to have a html page with all elements included, which I can use as "check list" of what has to be done.

Does anybody have or see such or similar page?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233089/is-there-a-giant-asset-page-of-all-bootstrap-elements-that-i-can-re-style - did you google before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the [twitter bootstrap](http://bootswatch.com/default/) and get html source and test your css and other functionality there.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This page http://bootswatch.com/default/ has the whole lot on one page. Easier than downloading the official docs, and it's updated when bootstrap changes.

Comment: Why have you answered on my question if you consider it as duplicate? Wanna earn some points? You should be consistent in your actions.